# How to change Form style without messing with code-behind?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, styles

Is there a tool or software to modify the style of C# Forms.

So I have an app/project written in C# and I want to change the style of the forms (if possible on another environment) without causing problems in the code-behind.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you clarify? What's the link between DAL&BLL and the style?

Comment: Data Access Layer and Business Logic Layer. So I was wondering if it's possible to change the form style without causing problems with the other layers.

Comment: Still not clear what you're trying to do. Why would a change in the form cause the DAL & BLL to change? This is usually a mark for bad design. If this is your case you should consider refactoring your application to decouple the UI (and code-behind) from BLL and DAL.

Comment: Someone who reads my question without examining the code, would suggest this. I totally agree with your comment. But I'm sure I've applied the rules of 3-Tier Layer, it's based on this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36847/Three-Layer-Architecture-in-C-NET I want to change the forms style without causing serious problems in the code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Custom Winform Styles](http://winformstyles.codeplex.com/) or [Drawing Custom Borders in Windows Forms](http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/) form *codeplex*.